# Unable to run yum command

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I'm unable to run `yum` command on my Linux machine.
I'm getting the following errors:

```
dispsim:~$ yum
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loading "rhnplugin" plugin
Loading "security" plugin
error: cannot open Packages index using db3 - Invalid argument (22)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in ?
    yummain.main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 85, in main
    base.getOptionsConfig(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 163, in getOptionsConfig
    disabled_plugins=self.optparser._splitArg(opts.disableplugins))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 164, in _getConf
ig
    self._conf = config.readMainConfig(startupconf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/config.py", line 685, in readMainCo
nfig
    yumvars['releasever'] = _getsysver(startupconf.installroot, startupconf.dist
roverpkg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/config.py", line 752, in _getsysver
    idx = ts.dbMatch('provides', distroverpkg)
TypeError: rpmdb open failed
```

Redhat-release is **Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.2 (Tikanga)**

```
dispsim-1:~$ uname -a
Linux dispsim 2.6.18-92.el5 #1 SMP Tue Apr 29 13:16:12 EDT 2008 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I also tried the following steps:

```
1. su
2. rm /var/lib/rpm/__db.00*
3. rpm --rebuilddb
```

But this didn't resolve the issue. Any suggestions on this please?

Comment: Please don't post *pictures* of text.  Just put the text itself into your question.

Comment: @larsks: Ok, made the changes.

Comment: Did the `rpm --rebuilddb` command log any errors?  When was the last time `rpm` was working correctly? Have there been any other problems (filesystem corruption, etc) prior to this issue?  What version of `rpm` is installed (`rpm --version`)?

Comment: @larsks: 1. `rpm --rebuilddb` command didn't throw any errors. 2. Many months ago I was able to run `yum clean all`. 3. I haven't seen any issues of filesystem corruption everything else is working fine. 4. **The Rpm version is 5.0**.

Comment: RHEL 5.x ships with RPM version 4.4.2.3 (or similar 4.4.x version).  It looks like maybe you have installed an incompatible version of rpm? Hard to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as su :

```
tar cvzf rpmdb-backup.tar.gz /var/lib/rpm
rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*
rpm --rebuilddb
rpm -qa  | sort
```

If this fails, execute first `lsof | grep /var/lib/rpm` and If it finds any, `kill -9` them all.

You could also try this sequence :

```
rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*
rpm --initdb
rpm --rebuilddb
```

If nothing works, copy the rpm database from a backup (or a nearly identical computer).

For the problem with locale, see the article [adjust locale settings on CentOS 7](http://www.virtualtothecore.com/en/quick-tip-adjust-locale-settings-centos-7-minimal-install/), that advises to add to `/etc/profile.d/locale.sh` commands such as:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Tried executing these commands, still no luck :(

Comment: I have expanded my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the help @harrymc. Nothing worked then I just copied `/var/lib/rpm` (tar and zip the folder) from another identical machine. After restarting the VM, `yum` worked. Thanks again :) Awarding bounty and +1 to you from my side :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you upgraded from 2010 RPM builds. Previously, SQLite was used to store information about packages, now it's BDB. You probably need to migrate your database.

To do so, you can run the following commands:

```
rpm --define '_dbapi 4' --rebuilddb
mv /var/lib/rpm /var/lib/rpm.bak
mv /var/lib/rpm.rebuild /var/lib/rpm
```

You can then test the new database with:

```
rpm -qa
```

Then it should work without issues.

Comment: After executing `rpm --define '_dbapi 4' --rebuilddb`, `/var/lib/rpm.rebuild` folder is not created.

Comment: Try running `updatedb` and then `locate rpm.rebuild` and check if it returns anything.

Comment: `rpm.rebuild` not found ever after running `updatedb` :(

Comment: Seems that in newer versions, the rebuilding happens in the `/var/lib/rpm` directory. Did you try running `yum` after running the `rpm --define '_dbapi 4' --rebuilddb` command?

Comment: it still did not work. Thanks for the help. harrymac steps worked for me. +1 form my side for helping me :)